# Using Half-Normal Plot to Identify Outlying Observations

Tags: regression, diagnostic, qq-plot

When we perform linear regression diagnostic, we usually utilize the half-normal plot (available in the `faraway` package in R) to identify outlying observations.

For example, if we want to identify large leverage points, we simply use haft-normal plot to plot the diagonal entries of the hat matrix and look for the outlying point(s). Note that there's no reason to expect a straight line in the half-normal plot, since there's no reason to assume quantities, such as the cook's distances or leverages, to be normally distributed.

Does anyone know why "unusually" large values will appear as outlying points in the half-normal plot? Is there any theory or proof behind this?

Comment: Who is included in "we" in your first sentence? (I know I rarely use this plot, for example, and when I do it's usually not specifically to identify outliers, so presumably you don't mean 'statisticians in general' -- you'd have no good basis to assert what is commonly done. Which then leaves me with "who, besides yourself, are we discussing"?)

Comment: Not outliers, but outlying observations. I think outliers usually refer to unusual response values, in which one can use "case deletion" and perform a hypothesis test to identify. What I was referring to is just simply any unusual large values in a vector of values. For instance, if we have a vector of values like `<1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 100 100000>`, then 100000 will appear as a outlying point in the half-normal plot.

Comment: I wasn't distinguishing outlying x from outlying y there, just generically talking about unusualness. I don't typically use half-normal plots for either

Comment: This is a built-in for JMP DOE analysis.  I'm sure they have robust documentation with references .. somewhere. http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Effect_Screening.shtml  http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Effect_Screening.shtml#908253

Comment: Yes, they're certainly built in to some software.

Comment: Thanks EngrStudent I'll check it out. @Glen_b what do you usually do to identify outlying observation then? Residual plot is hard to interpret because you don't really know how large a observation's residual has to be to actually cause problems. Thanks.

Comment: For an initial assessment of how influential an $x$-value might be I would look at leverage. More typically, that only matters so much if the y-residual is relatively large, in which case, I'd look at a plot of standardized residuals vs leverage, with lines of constant Cook's distance marked on (the software I use does this by default, so that's easy to do). But even that (and the half-normal plot as well) doesn't really tell you the extent to which it will "cause problems"; that depends on a variety of considerations, many of which lie outside the realm of statistics altogether

Comment: Faraway's book does so and my professor does so, so I assume it might be prevalent. I'm not targeting at any specific group.

Comment: Ah; useful information. Yes, Faraway's book is one of a number that do it (specifically in that case with leverages)

Comment: Faraway also uses this to check for influential observations (e.p cook's distance). It is pretty strange that he does this. But I guess it should have something to do with normalizing the scale of, for example, leverages. When you look at the residual plot, it is difficult to identify whether a observation is just a unlucky one or a unusual one.